# Have django-compressor leave <script type="module"> alone in non-production

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, es6-modules, django-compressor

For development (no `DJANGO_PRODUCTION`) I want to leave ES6 modules as-is, that means that if something is

```html
{% compress js %}
  <script src="{% static "path/to/some.js" %}" type="module"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

that it should still be `type="module"` afterwards.

Setting `COMPRESS_ENABLED` to `False` does not suffice and if I remove the `module` precompiler then I am getting the *"Couldn't find any precompiler in COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS setting for mimetype 'module'."* error message. Now I could just use `cat` as a precompiler (`COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (('module', 'cat'),)`) but the script tags would still be changed and `type="module"` removed.

So is there any way how I can easily prevent that? Preferably without too much special-casing of the non-production case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the official docs](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED):

> When COMPRESS_ENABLED is False the input will be rendered without any compression **except** for code with a mimetype matching one listed in the COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS setting

What can be done is creating a different COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS setting for development.

E.g.:

```
DEBUG = not os.environ.get('DJANGO_PRODUCTION')

if not DEBUG:
    COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
        ('module', 'browserify {infile} -t babelify --outfile {outfile}'),
    )
```

Comment: Ah OK, I tried this with an empty `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS` but not setting it at all is the solution!